# File upload validation Tornado Python

Tags: python, forms, file, upload, tornado

I found this examples to upload files to a server using Tornado Python Web framework but the thing is that none of the examples have error handling developed. If I submit the form with no file attached, it returns a 500 error. The idea is to set up the upload file field as optional not mandatory.

https://github.com/vamsiikrishna/tornado-upload

http://technobeans.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/tornado-file-uploads/

Could you please give me a hand?

I guess this may have an easy solution but I am quite a newbie.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googleing I found this solution:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

UPLOAD_FILE_PATH = '/path/to/files/'

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        args = dict(username = 'visitor')
        self.render('home.html', **args)

class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        username = self.get_argument('username', 'anonymous')
        if self.request.files.get('uploadfile', None):
            uploadFile = self.request.files['uploadfile'][0]
            filename = uploadFile['filename']
            fileObj = open(UPLOAD_FILE_PATH+username+filename, 'wb')
            fileObj.write(uploadFile['body'])
            self.redirect('/')

application=tornado.web.Application([(r'/',MainHandler),('/upload', UploadHandler) ],
template_path = 'templates',
debug = True
)

if __name__=='__main__':
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The think is the following condition placed before file request: `if self.request.files.get('uploadfile', None):`

Comment: You need to fix your code indentation, this is bogus Python code without the proper indentation.